# Does being std::move'd affect references?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I'm trying to make sense of some code I'm looking at, and one thing that I noticed is that one class keeps a reference to this one object in a reference member, while some other code move constructs it.

I'm curious how those play together. Is a reference member still valid if the underlying object is the source (or target) of a std::move operation?

How about if I happen to know that the underlying object has all its move operators custom defined to just std::move all its members? Presumably in that case the reference to it is valid when the source object being referenced is valid, and not valid when it isn't, right?

Comment: `std::move` doesn't do anything to an object. So whatever happens to the members depends on the specifics of the code you're looking at.

Comment: Can you add sample code to clarify?  It sounds like you have code which holds a reference to a moved-from variable - that is usually Bad News...

Comment: When you *move* from an object that object remains valid (in an indeterminate state) so any references to it continue to be valid. Its modified value can not be relied upon however so it should not be examined until it has been given a *new value*.

Comment: `std::move` applies to *values*, not variables. Values are never references.

Comment: *"while some other code move constructs it"* What does *it* stand for in this sentence - "that one class", "this one object", "a reference member", something else? It would be best if you showed the actual code in question, rather than trying to describe it in prose.